# QGIS Database Manager export removes properties (which is unwanted)

Tags: qgis, geojson, export, qgis-cloud, database-manager

I'm working with a QGIS server and when exporting a layer to a GeoJSON file, I 'm getting:

- The wrong CRS
- None of my properties

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Projecten",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 485875.830486575141549, 6609341.227111312560737 ], [ 485866.834653241792694, 6609370.331277979537845 ], [ 486062.097153241804335, 6609411.606277978979051 ], ...
```

it should be more like:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Projecten",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"prop1": "property 1", "prop2": "property2"}, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 485875.830486575141549, 6609341.227111312560737 ], [ 485866.834653241792694, 6609370.331277979537845 ], [ 486062.097153241804335, 6609411.606277978979051 ], ...
```

I tried different export formats. Those also did not return properties. The properties are however available in the attribute table.

I've looked for a solution online, without succes... Has anyone had this problem before that might show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: I know one thing that may hep with the CRS is to set it, otherwise I believe that it defaults to web Mercator or 3857. To set the CRS right click the layer and select Layer CRS, and then set the CRS to what you want.

Comment: Additionally, when you are exporting are you selecting fields to export and their export options?

Comment: I'm currently using version 3.22.12

Comment: changing the CRS from 3857 to the desired one works, thank you. However, although all columns are selected, the export does not include the properties. There are no additional options in the software that I can select. It is a database running on a QGISCloud server.

Comment: You may need to handle this with python and export it via custom code to get the properties.